# Spring Boot WAR deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I control in my Spring 2.1.4 Boot application (packaged as a WAR) whether I am creating a servlet 3.1 or 4.0 web application.  Normally, when using a web.xml web application descriptor, the attributes on the web-app would announce the version of the spec being used.  In a Spring WebApplicationInitializer application without a web.xml (which is my case), there is no such advertisement.

Is it just a matter of using only the servlet 3.1 features and deploying them to a container and hope that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web.xml` file is optional since Servlet 3 and Java EE 6 where annotations such as `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter`, `@WebListener` were introduced.

However, there is no way to declare this information outside the `web.xml` using the [`WebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) so you have to include the file anyway and specify the version.

Comment: How would a container know whether a WAR file without a web.xml made uses of capabilities that its implementation did not support?  For example, if the container is 3.1 compliant, would it only discover that the WAR included 4.0 features when it fails at runtime?  If so, the annotation should be updated in the spec to advertise the spec the WAR file requires, just like the web.xml currently does.

Answer (score 0):

After more than a year of posting this question I discovered that maven makes such determination by the presence of the specific API declared as a dependency. For example if you have the javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1 dependency in your Pom file maven will assume a servlet 4.0 container. I believe Spring boot does not support this but I think it should. As a sidenote the M2eclipse plug-in also works this way